# How to merge 3 columns into one column (With no gaps) in r

Tags: r

I have 3 separate columns and each row only has data in one of the columns, similar to the below...

```
| Country | Country 2 | Country 3 |
| ------- | --------- | --------- |
| UK      |           |           |
|         | France    |           |
|         |           | Germany   |
| Italy   |           |           |
| USA     |           |           |
|         | France    |           |
|         |           | Germany   |
```

I want to create one column which merges these together as below...

```
| Final Country |
| ------------- |
| UK            |
| France        |
| Germany       |
| Italy         |
| USA           |
| France        |
| Germany       |
```

I have tried using coalesce and paste, which seem to be working for 2 columns but not 3.

NB: This isn't the whole table, so I want to be able to select just 3 of the columns

Comment: This somehow feels like a problem that should not exist in the first place. Provided answers can be generalised for a set of columns, but perhaps there are better ways to handle  previous import / wrangling steps?

Comment: What's in the "missing" columns? Are they NA values? Or are they zero length strings? Or something else?

Answer (score 6):

In this scenario, a simple alternative approach using base R would be to just use `max` applied across rows ("stealing" Seth's data - thanks @Seth!):

```
df$finalcountry <- apply(df, 1, max)

#   country1 country2 country3 finalcountry
# 1       UK                             UK
# 2            France                France
# 3                    Germany      Germany
# 4    Italy                          Italy
# 5      USA                            USA
# 6            France                France
# 7                    Germany      Germany
```

If you want to only apply it across certain columns, you can specify columns however you'd like, ie:

```
wantcols <- 2:4
# or
wantcols <- grep("country", names(df))
# or
wantcols <- c("country1", "country2", "country3")

df$finalcountry <- apply(df[wantcols], 1, max)

#   other_data country1 country2 country3 finalcountry
# 1         88       UK                             UK
# 2         81            France                France
# 3         76                    Germany      Germany
# 4        100    Italy                          Italy
# 5         60      USA                            USA
# 6         70            France                France
# 7         82                    Germany      Germany
```

And if you wanted it in a separate data frame:

```
data.frame(finalcountry = apply(df[wantcols], 1, max))

#   finalcountry
# 1           UK
# 2       France
# 3      Germany
# 4        Italy
# 5          USA
# 6       France
# 7      Germany
```

Note if you have `NA` values instead of true blank spaces, add `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
apply(df[wantcols], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Reposting @Seth's data for posterity:

```
df <- data.frame(other_data = sample(50:100, 7),
                 country1 = c('UK','','','Italy','USA','',''),
                 country2 = c('','France','','','','France',''),
                 country3 = c('','','Germany','','','','Germany'))
```

Answer (score 4):

*edit* Question clarified need to only paste some columns. Updated column selection.

You could use `tidyr::unite()` to paste multiple columns, providing a specified set of columns by name, or using a `tidy-select` function as in this example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(col = 'Final_Country',
        starts_with('country'),
        sep = '',
        remove = TRUE)
#>   other_data Final_Country
#> 1         83            UK
#> 2         98        France
#> 3         80       Germany
#> 4         59         Italy
#> 5         70           USA
#> 6         63        France
#> 7         72       Germany
```

#### Data

```
structure(list(other_data = c(77L, 63L, 94L, 73L, 82L, 52L, 80L
), country1 = c("UK", "", "", "Italy", "USA", "", ""), country2 = c("", 
"France", "", "", "", "France", ""), country3 = c("", "", "Germany", 
"", "", "", "Germany")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R alternative:

```
> data.frame(Final_Country = apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse=""))
  Final_Country
1            UK
2        France
3       Germany
4         Italy
5           USA
6        France
7       Germany
```

And another dplyr solution using `coalesce`:

```
> df %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(., ""))) %>% 
    do.call(coalesce, .) %>% 
    data.frame(Final_country = .)
  Final_country
1            UK
2        France
3       Germany
4         Italy
5           USA
6        France
7       Germany
```

I also took data from @Seth.

Answer (score 1):

A [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) version:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- data.frame(
         country_1 = c("UK", "", "", "Italy", "USA", "", ""),
         country_2 = c("", "France", "", "", "", "France", ""),
         country_3 = c("", "", "Germany", "", "", "", "Germany")
)

setDT(DF)
DF[, country := do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = names(DF)]
print(DF)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to transpose the data and subset those which are not `''`.

```
x <- DF[c("country1", "country2", "country3")] #select the 3 columns

x <- t(x)  #transpose the data
x[x != ''] #Get those which are not empty
#x[!is.na(x) & x != ''] #In case there are NA
#[1] "UK"      "France"  "Germany" "Italy"   "USA"     "France"  "Germany"
```

Or using `max.col`.

```
x <- DF[c("country1", "country2", "country3")] #select the 3 columns

x[cbind(seq_len(nrow(x)), max.col(x != ''))]
#x[cbind(seq_len(nrow(x)), max.col(!is.na(x) & x != ''))]  #In case there are NA
#[1] "UK"      "France"  "Germany" "Italy"   "USA"     "France"  "Germany"
```

Or using `paste0` in `do.call`.

```
x <- DF[c("country1", "country2", "country3")] #select the 3 columns

#x[is.na(x)] <- ''  #In case there are NA
do.call(paste0, x)
#[1] "UK"      "France"  "Germany" "Italy"   "USA"     "France"  "Germany"
```

Or using `pmax` in `do.call`.

```
x <- DF[c("country1", "country2", "country3")] #select the 3 columns

#x[is.na(x)] <- ''  #In case there are NA
do.call(pmax, x)
#[1] "UK"      "France"  "Germany" "Italy"   "USA"     "France"  "Germany"
```

Data

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:7,
                 country1 = c('UK','','','Italy','USA','',''),
                 country2 = c('','France','','','','France',''),
                 country3 = c('','','Germany','','','','Germany'),
                 b = 7:1)
```

---

Benchmark

```
x <- DF[c("country1", "country2", "country3")] #select the 3 columns

bench::mark(
           max.col = x[cbind(seq_len(nrow(x)), max.col(x != ''))],
           applyPaste = apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse=""),  # @Jilber Urbina
           applyMax = apply(x, 1, max),  # @jpsmith
           t = {y <- t(x); y[y != '']},
           pamx = do.call(pmax, x),
           paste0 = do.call(paste0, x)
       )
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 max.col    67.07µs 72.85µs    13211.    2.91KB     32.3  6138    15    464.6ms
#2 applyPaste 48.62µs 53.49µs    18218.      432B     30.1  8484    14    465.7ms
#3 applyMax    41.5µs 44.65µs    21755.      432B     32.7  9985    15      459ms
#4 t          24.06µs 26.39µs    36081.      432B     32.5  9991     9    276.9ms
#5 pamx        5.74µs  6.57µs   147943.        0B     44.4  9997     3     67.6ms
#6 paste0      2.56µs  2.91µs   319035.        0B     31.9  9999     1     31.3ms
```